# Grammaticality and formality of "When can I call you?"

Tags: grammaticality, formality

When can I call you.  ...does it make sense? Shall I use this for formal talk?

Please help me as I have used the same sentence when I called HR.

Need your input on this

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it's fine. [When is the best time to call you?](http://themainstreetgroup.com/join-as-a-client/) is a more polite way to say it, though.